# Entering UK with dependant visa

Tags: uk, uk-residents

I hold a valid UK Residence Permit as a dependant of my parent. I study in the UK, but because of the COVID-19 situation, currently I am back in my home country with my parent and most probably my parent whom my visa is dependant on would go back to the UK in February. I might need to make a short trip to the UK to attend an interview next month. I wonder if the UK Border Force allows people with dependant BRPs to enter UK on their own? Or if they require the main visa holder (parent in this case) be in the UK when the dependant tries to enter on their own.

For further clarification, my BRP does not have any endorsement or whatsoever saying "Accompanied by, joined by, etc..." it just says "dependant, leave to enter" on it.

Comment: If you are under 18 years old you may want to read the PDF via this link. Leaflet explaining Border Force's legal obligations to keep children safe:  https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/children-travelling-to-the-uk

Comment: @canonacer - I'm over 18 in my case. Just wondering if the Border Force allows dependant BRP holders to enter UK on their own or not. Thanks for the shared info